# How do double D.Va ultimates work?

Tags: overwatch

For example, if I am out of my mech, and then I can recall the mech. Should I get killed instead? If get killed instead I will have another mech and a more powerful ultimate.

Everytime I do my ultimate I can always get another mech quickly afterwards.

In fact there is a case where I ultimate, kill people, get another mech, get the mech destroyed, get another mech, and then ultimate again.

I have no idea how that works.

Do two ultimates get charged simultaneously? If so, then what's being displayed then?

Answer (score 9):

D.Va is unique in that she has two ultimates. They charge separately.

Self-destruct behaves like other ultimates. It is charged by dealing damage and over time, while in her mech . It persists through death.

Call mech is reset to 0 whenever D.Va's mech is destroyed. This means that if D.Va is killed while on foot, she will not retain Call Mech charge. It is charged in the usual way- damage and time while on foot- relatively quickly. It is instantly fully charged when her mech self-destructs or if she is resurrected by Mercy.

D.va's interface and voice lines will only display and reflect the relevant ultimate. Annoyingly, this means there is no way to see her self-destruct progress while on foot, or waiting to respawn.

Comment: Side note: If the mech is destroyed before it can self-destruct (e.g. you drop it off the side of the map), the call mech "ultimate" does not automatically charge to full.

Comment: Note that the ultimate only gains charge when it kills. if you whiff your ultimate and damages no one you'll gain no charge.

Comment: @Riley You don't need a kill to get the ultimate charge, just doing damage is mostly enough to get it.

Comment: @Riley Just tested it on a map with no players. Still got full charge when it blew up.

Comment: @Studoku Odd, I whiffed my ult yesterday and was on 0%

Comment: @Studoku On the training map? Or just a custom game map?

Comment: @Lyrion Custom game with no players, so nobody could claim I accidentally hit a training bot.

Comment: @Studoku D.Va's Call Mech will recharge 3 seconds after she initiates self destruct- i.e. when her old mech explodes. It used to be 4 seconds before the buff, but they lowered it to keep it in line with her fuse timer. She does not have to hit anyone with it, but if the mech does NOT explode (if it falls off a cliff), she won't get a new mech.

Comment: @Studoku Also of note: Blocking damage does not grant charge for any character that can (Zarya, Reinhardt, Winston, D.Va, Mei). It grants fire points, but does not contribute to your ultimate charge rate. Only damage and healing affect it (which I think is kind of unfair, but y'know).